BoxPropsColorOverrides missing from React MUI
It seems the Box component doesn't have BoxPropsColorOverrides, but the augmented Palette colors actually work if they are defined.
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface Palette {
    customColor: string;
  }

  interface PaletteOptions {
    customColor?: string;
  }
}

Both of these work fine, but the second shorthand version has no code completion with TypeScript, which you would have if there was BoxPropsColorOverrides.
<Box color={(theme) => theme.palette.customColor} />
<Box color="customColor" />

I've tried to augment other modules but still only seeing system color options for Box component. My project has strictly set custom colors which would be nice to use in the shorthand manner instead of having to select colors through theme palette every time. Is it possible to add such TypeScript support at all for Box or by default to all components?
